# Delphi - Disable [x] Close Button in VCL Styles

Tags: delphi

I'd like disable [X] close Button with VCL Style in DX Berlin.

Wy this code do not work wiht VCL Style?

```
EnableMenuItem(GetSystemMenu(Form3.Handle, LongBool(False)),SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND or MF_GRAYED);
```

Comment: It seems you have hit a bug in the style engine? Have you also noted that disabling `SC_CLOSE` as above, **does not** disable `Alt - F4`, not even in a non styled app.

Comment: @Tom In Delphi 10 Seattle, it seems to work as expected. Haven't tried 10.1 Berlin yet though.

Comment: @Jerry What works as expected? Do you refer to OP's issue or my comment regarding Alt-F4? I have tested in both Seattle and Berlin

Comment: @Tom Referring to your comment, `ALT-F4` behaves as expected. Unless I misunderstood you. \

Comment: @Jerry Depends on your expectations :) After OP's code line, and since the system menu "Close - Alt F4" is visually in a disabled state, I would expect the key combination "Alt" and "F4" to also be disabled, which it isn't (Seattle and Berlin on W7).

Answer (score 5):

If you set the action in the `FormClose` event to `caNone`, when you try to close the form (clicking on the red cross) nothing is going to happen. In this way you can disable the button.

```
procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
 //You cannot type only caNone, otherwise you'll get a compiler error
 Action := TCloseAction.caNone;
end;
```

You can find caNone in `System.UITypes`; read the [documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TCloseAction.html) for more information.

Comment: Ok, but how can i close my form? Exit from program?? If I use  Action := TCloseAction.caNone, perfect, but not exit from app.

Comment: @JuniorOliveira In the form, declare a private boolean, e.g. `AllowToClose` and change the forms `OnClose ` event to `if not AllowToClose then Action := TCloseAction.caNone;` Then, when you want to close the form programmatically, you simply set `AllowToClose := True;` and call `Form.Close`.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JuniorOliveira Also don't forget to notify the user as of why he can't close the application at this time. I personally hate when application doesn't want to close and also doesn't tell me why. And yes I will find the way to close that application whether you as a developer want or not (you can always forcibly kill application from Task Manager). So make sure to tell your users why they have to wait before the can close the application.

Comment: OK. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

When using VCL Styles by default style affect the appearance of fonts being used, client area of your form and also your forms border (this also include minimize, maximize and close buttons).

So from what I see you have two options:

1. You could change `StyleElements` property of your form to `[seFont, seClient]` which means that style will only be applied to used fonts and client area of your form but the border area of your form would be unstyled and rendered by OS.
2. You modify the style at runtime in order to achieve desired effect. Unfortunately I don't have enough experience with Styles to present you with an example of how to achieve this.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot.